# Wait asynchronous .ajaxComplete() before form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, submit

I need to override form's submit method to wait until the ajax request will be completed. At the same time, ajax request should be asynchronous to display a progress indicator, also default form handler must be continued after response receiving.

I can't use event.preventDefault() and then manual call form.submit() for this, because form sending results should be opened in the new tab of the browser. If form.submit() will be called from the code, then some browsers (i.e. chrome) will block the new tab/window.

Pseudocode for clarity:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  var result;
  startIndicator();
  asyncAjaxCheckResults();  // ajax complete handler changed 'result' var
  stopIndicator(); // stopping indicator after async ajax will be completed

  // continue with default submit behavior if we received desired result
  // else prevent executing 
  if (result !== 'desired result') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Can anything be done in this case? Maybe $.deferred can help or infinity loop?

Comment: An infinite loop will not help with anything but freezing the browser and triggering "long running script"-errors.

Comment: I'd look at Jquery.When() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a sync ajax call, so the script will wait for the respons and then continue running.

$.ajax({

...

async:false,

...

});

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: No, synchronous ajax calls should *not* be used, they even are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to add click event to the submit button instead submit event to the form, 
send the ajax and use event.prevenrDefault, on ajax success callback fire the form submit - $('#form').submit().